# in range() statement doesnt work

Tags: python, if-statement

`So I am just making something to test if I can make certain outputs based on inputs

Each time I try to enter an answer, nothing happens here
I used if elif statements with the in range() in them.
Nothing shows up when I type the answer

```
from random import randint
from termcolor import colored
repeat = True
from termcolor import colored
import time
import sys
import multiprocessing


   print colored("Hello, this is a program to help you practice algebraic 
    expressions.","magenta")
    print("")
     time.sleep(4)
     print colored("Alright let's start with something very basic...\nWhat is x 
     if 
     2x 
     = 32?","magenta")
     prob = int(raw_input())
   if int(prob) in range (16, 16):
     print colored("Well done, you got the warmup correct","yellow")
   elif int(prob) in range(1, 15):
     print colored("Incorrect answer try again","red")
```

Comment: I tried to format your code but your indentation is off, please fix it.

Comment: what do you expect `if int(prob) in range (16, 16):` to do? cause it's basically doing nothing right now.

Comment: Your code only covers inputs between 1 and 14.

Comment: I did in range (16, 16) because everything else failed

Comment: If you check what `range(16, 16)` returns, it will make sense.

Comment: Why don't you use `if prob == 16: ... else:...` is also mean if 16 true  and everything else failed .

Comment: You should google *"python range"* to find the doc and see what it does... range(16,16) is an empty range. Nothing is in that range.

Answer (score 0):

This line `if int(prob) in range(16,16):` is problem. Function `range(x,y)` generates list equals to [x,y), which means starting with x and including x, ending with y excluding y, so by that, you are asking if your number is in empty array. 
Example: 
    `list_of_numbers = range(12,16)` gives us list with elements `list_of_numbers = [12,13,14,15]`

Answer (score -1):

I have written this code removing all the functions that you haven't used and the coloured text which seemed to always error. range is generally used in "for" loops but in conditionals you need to use == if it is equal to > for greater than < less than != not equal to e.t.c.

```
import time
print ("Hello, this is a program to help you practice algebraic 
expressions.")
print("")
time.sleep(4)
prob =int (input("Alright let's start with something very basic What is 
x if 2x = 32? "))

if prob ==16:
    print("Well done, you got the warmup correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect answer try again")
           `
```

Comment: don't understand what the problem with the answer is